# Why can't I add a earlier xamarin forms version as a nuget into my Xamarin forms project/android package?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this project and I have had some issues with it when I try to debug it as android. 
I have come up with a solution but only if I use a earlier version of xamarin forms (1.3) in the androidpackage.

When I search for Xamarin forms on my other projects in my NuGet gallery I can see both 1.3 and 2.0 versions and add it as a package.

But in this partcular project where I need the 1.3 version I can only see the 2.0 version.

Comment: I just can't get it why i can see the 1.3 version on some projects on others i cant.. so annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nuget "Package Manager" on Mac or Linux as it is implemented via **PowerShell** and that does not exist on Mac/Linux in a form that will work (There is the OSS PASH project but it does not provide enough functionality for Nuget's Package Manager).

Manually edit your `package.config` with the versions that you need as the other answer says and do a restore on it.

### Existing Xamarin.Forms 2.x `package.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.0.0.6490" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
</packages>
```

### Edit your `package.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="1.3.5.6335" targetFramework="MonoAndroid60" />
</packages>
```

### Xamarin Studio / Package Restore

Right-click on the `Packages` in the Solution Pad and perform a `Restore`

Note: Xamarin installs a shell wrapper for `nuget.exe` and it is called `nuget`.

Comment: Ok got the code in but my project does not seem to like this at all. I get 235 errors, and they are something like this: Projectname.Droid.Resource.Id "does not contain a defintion for fill", Projectname.Droid.Resource.Layout, Projectname.Droid.Resource.Style, etc.

Comment: I want it to obviously run on the 2.0 xamarin forms version but I tried to make it work alright with the 1.3 version but it doesnt seem to run on this project

Comment: the application starts now atleast but i get an error in my mainactivityfile (android) on this code: "LoadApplication (new App ());" a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 1):

If you use the NuGet package manager either from a command line or the Visual Studio Package Manager window you can specify which version you want to install.

From command line:

```
nuget install Xamarin.Forms -Version 1.3.5.6337
```

From VS Package Manager window:

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Forms -Version 1.3.5.6337
```

Alternatively you can create a package.config for each project folder and add the following lines to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="1.3.5.6337" targetFramework="<your target framework>" />
</packages>
```

Then after adding this restore NuGet packages for your project.

The `<your target framework>` will depend on which project type you want to install it into.

Comment: Okok, which one is the easiest to implement? Do i find this under "tools" in xamarin forms?

Comment: There is no "tools" menu in Xamarin.Forms. You probably mean Xamarin.Studio, which is a no as well. So pop into the command line. Note the above is for a windows environment, if you are on a Mac, I am not sure if NuGet.exe behaves well if you run it with mono.

Comment: In my xamarin forms (I use mac) I see a "tools" option and i also see a "project"  option where I can choose between these categories: Add NuGet Package (which doesnt work, cant find the version), Update Nuget Package, Restore NuGet package.

Comment: I don't think you can specify which version you want to install in the NuGet package manager built into Xamarin.Studio.

Comment: Ok, i am a bit confused now. Command line and Package manager is for windows only?

Comment: If you can find the NuGet.exe that Xamarin.Studio uses, you can probably use that by writing `mono` infront of the first command I gave you

Comment: Under "project" i find something called "Create package", should i do something with that?